# CKeditor-4, how to disable Font-Symbol?

Tags: utf-8, ckeditor

My [online CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) (that now is using *CKEditor v4.2.2*)  not supports `<font face="Symbol">`, so *online edit tool* must  preserve the "purity" of the UTF-8 of the online editions.

The problem arises when a user copy/paste from a external text to the CKeditor box,

```
 <p><font face="Symbol">&bull; </font>blabla 
    <font face="Symbol">S</font> blabla;</p>
```

**Can CKEditor transform these `<font face="Symbol">` into "free UTF-8"?** That is, can CKEditor save

```
 <p>&#8226; blabla &#931; blabla;</p>
```

There are some configuration to enforce only UTF8 characters, without font-symbol?

---

EDITED: my configurations for test contextualization,

```
  CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( event ) {  // contenteditable
      var editor = event.editor;
      // ...
      editor.on( 'configLoaded', function() {
           editor.config.skin           = '...';
           // ...
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to solve this, you need to find a dictionary of these characters which will allow you to translate original characters to their UTF-8 representation.

To apply this transformation to all `font` elements use the [`dataProcessor`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor). The [`dataFilter`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor-property-dataFilter) is applied to all data loaded or inserted into editor.

```
editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( {
    elements: {
        font: function( el ) {
            // el will be an instance of CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element
            // el.children[ 0 ] will be an instance of CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text
            // You'll need to read a value of that text, replace
            // all characters with their UTF-8 representatives
            // and return:
            return new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text( text );
            // That will replace font tags with returned text nodes.
        }
    }
} );
```

Here you can find more complex exampled of dataProcessor usage: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Create-new-dom-elements-using-dataProcessor.htmlFilter

Comment: Thanks @Reinmar, you're the CKeditor-Man, so I'm sure your answer is correct! The [oficial dictionary is here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/ADOBE/symbol.txt)... But I need a little bit more of your help for copy/paste your code (using `return new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text( 'HelloWorld' );`) into the CKedtitor implementation, see my edited addendum in the question text -- not working, where I need to copy/paste your code?

Comment: The optimal place will be in `editor#pluginsLoaded` listener. The data processor instance will be ready by then. You could also add it in `editor#instanceReady` listener, but that's after data are filtered, so your filter would miss data loaded at startup.